# How to upload file in WinForms?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello I'm  newer in VB net and in WinForms so maybe my question will seem naive.

I am using .net2.

I need to upload a file to the WinForms application and store it in specific folder.
In Web application I implemented it with help of the fileUpload Control.

Any idea how can I implement this in a WinForms application?

Comment: From folder in desktop to the another folder in disc D:\ .

Comment: `File.Copy` should do. Select the file using `FileDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing because you mentioned uploading whih would indicate transfer to/from an internet location but in your comment it appears you just want to copy a file from the desktop to the D drive.

This code should do what you want:

```
Dim sourceFile As String = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "foo.txt")
Dim destinationFile As String = "D:\folder\foo.txt"
File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile)
```

Note: You can use the same code to copy a file in a web application you do not need to use a FileUpload control

Answer (score 2):

A Simple way to Upload a file to a target URL is by using the `UploadFIleAsync` function which can be found in `System.Net.WebClient()`.

**For example:**

```
Dim WithEvents myClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

Public Function Upload(ByVal tURL As String, ByVal file As String) As Boolean
        Dim uri As New System.Uri(tURL)
        Me.myClient.UploadFileAsync(uri, file)

Return true 'Needs some modification, this is a simple code, but should work as it is
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm.. I hope you were referring to UPLOADING a file and not Loading a file from the local computer ;)